# Passing parameters to built unit test DLL via console

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

Is it possible to pass parameters to a Microsoft unit test DLL via the console? I want to do this as I have a thousands of test cases stored in XML, I dont want to include the XML files as a resource in the visual studio project as I dont want to have to recompile the test solution every time we want to modify the test data. I am using VS 2010 and MSUnit testing framework.

Comment: Why not just keep the xml data in a file at a known (relative) path? If a test case loads that data when running the tests, you don't have to recompile after a data change. Just switch file at the known location and run again!?

Comment: This is tagged as Nunit, but your question says MSUnit, do you mean the MS Test framework that ships as part of VS 2010?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't really pass command line arguments to mstest that the test suite can use, however you can specify a test settings file that can contain deployment items.

Your tests would consume the file as though it is relative to the path the tests are running in; each test settings file can specify different files, assuming that the names files names remain the same.